# Building Web Content and Word Documents

Tags: html, ms-word, ms-office

What is the best tool for breaking down Word docs into a series of 
strong, em, a, br, and p tags.

I'd like to drop all other info.

The built-in Word 2007 "Filtered" HTML "Save As" doesn't work that well. Other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Code: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/000485.html
Tool: http://www.textism.com/wordcleaner/